# How can i connect a contact form with email with php

Tags: php, html, email

I have a contact form that is coded in this way:

**HTML CODE**

```
 <form enctype="text/plain" action="send_form_email.php" method="post" role="form">
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<input name="Emri" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Emri">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<input name="Email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
<input name="Sbjekti" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subjekti">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
<textarea name="Msazhi" rows="5" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Mesazhi"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<input name="Dergo" type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit" value="DERGO">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>
</form>
```

I have connected it with a php code called send_form_email.php

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "xhesjanatopalli@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<?php

}
?>
```

I have added my email address, but this is not working, when i click submit, send_form_email.php is being downloaded.
Can anyone please help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Remove `enctype="text/plain"`

Comment: what do you get when you manually open the php file in browser?

Comment: php file downloads itself

Comment: Looks like your HTTP server is not configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side scripting language, are you running your code in a server that support PHP?

If not, you can easily setup your PHP enviroment with a software like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/it/index.html)

Comment: so in XAMPP i may need to create a database?

Comment: @xhesjana Nope, you can use XAMPP to run your PHP code, but maybe  
you will have some problems sending email from localhost. You can also try an hosting. Where do you want to deploy you application?

Comment: i will put my code in cpanel accelerated 2, actually i have a website in this host but i want to put new code for a new design.